# How do I trace my python program from start of execution to finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, trace

I have a function written in python, and I want to inspect how it runs step by step from start to finish. How do I go about doing this?

I am using PyCharm as an IDE, but I don't know if it has a tracing feature.

Any tips or resources that are newbie friendly on this issue?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a profiler. Luckily, PyCharm is really powerful and comes with a wealth of [debugging/profiling tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/profiler.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will look at this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your code within PyCharm, simply set a [breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/breakpoints.html) on the first line within the function you wish to examine, then step through it using their interface.

If you're running your code via the commandline, I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with Python's debugging module, [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). All you need to do to examine your function is temporarily add the line:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

.. as the first line of your function. When you run it and it hits this line, you can step through the execution on the commandline using simple directives like 'n' for next line.

Comment: Hi luke, thanks for answering. I am running my code within PyCharm, can you recommend a link to any videos available to see how to set a breakpoint and doing the step through?

Comment: I couldn't find anything official, but this fella gives a reasonable PyCharm specific overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pv7qVcoNTk

If you pre-read about the concepts here, it'll help:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-line-breakpoints.html

Comment: I find that the `ipython` debugger is significantly nicer to work withthan `pdb`. Use the line `from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer; Tracer()()`